# Problem drawing a line and understanding the passed data

Tags: angular, d3.js

I try to render [this example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/hierarchical-edge-bundling) in my angular app.
So same data, I copy the functions, etc.

I can see the circle with the nodes, but I have problems drawing the paths/links.

My problem lies in this function:

```
line = d3.lineRadial()
    .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.85))
    .radius(d => d.y)
    .angle(d => d.x)
```

Where do I know what `d` is?
My IDE says, it's a vector of 2 numbers but when I log the data, it's a node with x and y values in it.
But if I try to access them and write `d.x`, I get the error `TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type '[number, number]'.`

This is how my function looks right now:

```
let line = d3.lineRadial()
      .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.85))
      .radius((d,i) => {
        console.log("d");
        console.log(i);
        console.log(d);
        return d[0];
      })
      .angle(d => d[1]);
```

And this is the log output:

[image: log output]

I am a bit confused, how the log can tell me something different at runtime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just check a bit the d3 docs (perhafs someone with more experience can help you more), but we are going to begin with some easy:

```
array=[[10, 60], [40, 90], [60, 10], [190, 10]]
p=d3.line()(this.array)
```

create in SVG a path with the points of the lines

```
<svg fill="transparent" stroke="black">
  <path [attr.d]="p"/>
</svg>
```

When you have a d3.lineRadial you "feed" with an array of values "angle and radius"

```
  array=[[0, 0][1.0471975511965976, 2][2.0943951023931953, 4]....]
  p=d3.line()(this.array)
```

But calculate the radius and angle is some "hard". So, we can create a function (1)

```
myfunction=d3.lineRadial()
  .angle((d, i) => (Math.PI / 4) * i)
  .radius((d, i) => (length - i) * 2)
```

And we can use this function to create the "path" of a svg

```
p=this.myfunction({length:13})
```

If you want to "rounded" the "spiral" use `.curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.85))` Well, you can use all in an unique instrucction

```
 p = d3
    .lineRadial()
    .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.85))
    .angle((d, i) => (Math.PI / 4) * i)
    .radius((d, i) => (length - i) * 2)({length:13});
```

(1) See how work the function, you use,e.g. `.angle((d,i)=>a function of "i"`. then, when you execute the function with an object with property `length` i goes from 0 to length-1 and return [0, PI/4,2*PI/4,3*PI/4,...]. but `d` is nothing